# file transfer between host macine(win10) and virtualbox machine(centos 6.3)

Tags: centos, files

I am trying to copy some files from my host machine to my virtual box machine centos. I tried vsftpd and share folder but it's not working.

Comment: I suggest you use `ftp`, `scp` or shared folders, if that doesn't work for you, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain how you tried `vsftpd` and shared folders and exactly how they failed.

Comment: @Anthon does win10 support scp?

Comment: @milad Sure, why wouldn't it? Windoze is not that non-functional. It  is just a protocol on top of  TCP.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best tool to transfer file is [rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)

It allow you to transfer and syncing securely data.

example:

```
~/origin/ rsync -aHSv --progress user@000.000.000.000:~/data/
```

The first time it will sync and send the data, all next time it will send just the files that have changed.